# I have the answer to a question I wrote that was deleted

Tags: support, deleted-questions, self-answer

About a year ago I wrote a question and it was immediately deleted because I didn't provide enough context. But I now would be able to answer it. I saw on some of the meta questions that you can indeed answer your own questions. What I would like to know is if it's worth to undelete the question so I can answer it myself. In that case I heard I would need to contact a moderator since I do not have enough reputation. If it's not worth it would it be better to write the question again? Or should I just not do anything?

Comment: The main thing is that whatever form this question takes, whether it is an undeleted old question or a brand new one, it will be judged as a *question*; the fact that you answer it yourself will not magically make the question brilliant. So if you undelete the old question, you need to undelete *and edit to improve*. Saying something along the lines of what you have said here would be decent context though.

Comment: @user1729 yeah but I could also add more context to the question

Comment: I think you should post your answer (don't know which of the two options it's best tho). I'd assume it's new content, in the sense that your question it's not a duplicated one. You know, math.SE is very big.

Comment: I think what folks are saying here, is that if you are able to undelete the question, *after editing to improve the question*, and then you would post your answer, that would be fine. If you need for the question to be undeleted and reopened (if it had been closed) that would likely require a moderator's action, unless you deleted the question yourself.

Comment: @amWhy no it was deleted by a modereator